# Menu behaves differently in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I'm working on a site that works as expected in Chrome but opening it in Internet Explorer a see that the navigation menu is out of place.
Investigating the problem a saw that not all the list items are wrapped inside the main ul and 2 list items do not have the correct class.

The one with the problem:

[image]

The correct one:

[image]

My project is made using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Umbraco CMS. The menu View looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="@(CurrentPage.Url == "/" ? "current_page_item" : null)"><a class="Lvl1 home" href="/">Home</a></li>

@foreach (var item in menuItems)
{
<li class="@(CurrentPage.Id == item.Id ? "current_page_item" : null) Col1">
    <a class="lvl1 parent" href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>

    @{ var subMenuItems = item.Children.Where("Visible"); }

    @if (subMenuItems.Count() > 0)
    {
        <ul>
            <li>
            @foreach (var sub in subMenuItems)
            {
                if (sub.HasValue("menuItemImage"))
                {
                    <div class="NavItemHolder">
                        <div class="NavItemImage">
                            <a href="@sub.Url"><img src="@Umbraco.Field(sub, "menuItemImage", recursive: true)"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="NavItemDesc">
                            <a href="@sub.Url">
                            <span>@sub.Name</span><br>
                            <span>@sub.menuItemInfo</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {<li><a class="parent" href="@sub.Url">@sub.Name</a></li>}
            }
            </li>
        </ul>
    }
</li>
}
</ul>
```

This works fine in Chrome, and cant seem to find the problem for IE.

Comment: Why have you put the list tags outside of the sub menu item loop?

Comment: I guess I copied the html from the original site, but I corrected it now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a new list item for each submenu rather than wrapping all the submenus in one list item (or otherwise nesting list items without separating them into proper nested lists with a `ul` wrapper).

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="@(CurrentPage.Url == "/" ? "current_page_item" : null)"><a class="Lvl1 home" href="/">Home</a></li>

@foreach (var item in menuItems)
{
<li class="@(CurrentPage.Id == item.Id ? "current_page_item" : null) Col1">
    <a class="lvl1 parent" href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>

    @{ var subMenuItems = item.Children.Where("Visible"); }

    @if (subMenuItems.Count() > 0)
    {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var sub in subMenuItems)
            {
                <li>
                if (sub.HasValue("menuItemImage"))
                {
                    <div class="NavItemHolder">
                        <div class="NavItemImage">
                            <a href="@sub.Url"><img src="@Umbraco.Field(sub, "menuItemImage", recursive: true)"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="NavItemDesc">
                            <a href="@sub.Url">
                            <span>@sub.Name</span><br>
                            <span>@sub.menuItemInfo</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {<a class="parent" href="@sub.Url">@sub.Name</a>}
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
</li>
}
</ul>
```